# Setup corda NETWORK using network bootstrapper + postgres

Tags: postgresql, networking, h2, corda

I am following [this](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/network-bootstrapper.html?search-input=node.conf) doc.
There is a show stopper in this.

It's explained that, point network bootstrapper jar to _node.conf files in the directory to generate network-related files, but **never mentioned how does _node.conf file must look like**, especially with configuration for different aspects like H2 DB, PostgresDB etc.

Share a sample link( **not cordapp**, I just need **network** setup examples ) or steps to set up a network with h2 & Postgres.

Not many articles available on the internet, everything takes me to the official document and it just increases confusion or convinces me to stop working.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `gradle deployNodes`, it will generate all the nodes configuration files that are needed by the Network Bootstrapper inside a `/build/nodes` folder, which will be created by that gradle task.

You can also find all the files in [this repository](https://github.com/ashutoshmeher-r3/docker-corda) used in an older bootcamp (but still valid) about how to deploy the nodes using Docker. The configuration files are the same.
You can also find an example of node configuration file in the documentation [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/corda-configuration-file.html#configuration-examples).
There is also a very good [tutorial video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmRMQsJSDMg) made by R3 specifically for network bootstrapper.

Comment: so for me to use corda network bootstrapped I must first setup a gradle project with task deployNodes? isn't there anything simpler than that ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "simpler". As I said in my answer, you can also use Docker Compose with the static files already available in this example repo https://github.com/ashutoshmeher-r3/docker-corda: you just need to run "docker-compose run".
If you already have a cordapp in your IDE, the network bootstrapper is invoked by gradle deployNodes. It depends on what you need/want. Both are extremely simple.